# Android and iphone app geographic blocking limited to download and not use

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Is it possible to limit geographic blocking to downloading an app only and not use? In other words, that I can only download the app in a specific country, but that I can use it anywhere using Google Play Store or iStore distribution settings?

Comment: Apple allows you to specify which countries stores your app should appear in. The ability to download is limited to the location associated with the users account, not their physical location. So someone with a us account can download from the us store even if they are in Austalia. There are no restrictions on where they can use the app once it is downloaded

Comment: Thanks, verified this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play store does not have control over where(Geo-graphically) the app is being used once it is downloaded on to the users phone.

Using Google Playstore you can only restrict the download of the app and not its usage.

The settings can be found under Pricing & Distribution section as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope this helps and I am not sure about the Apple part because I am android guy.

Comment: Thanks Kowshick, where can I find this in the reference material? I want to be 100% sure that I can download the app in my country only, but be able to use it abroad once it has been downloaded.

Comment: You can find details about country specific distribution here https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html.  Google PlayStore is just a distribution medium from where users can download your app, once it downloaded on to the phone play store does not have control on application usage. Even if you want to restrict such usage it needs to be done by your app and your servers, you need to implement Geo-blocking  based in IP-address or lat-long we had used AKAMAI services to implement this in a app that I had worked some time back. But I could not find concrete supporting docs.